# How to put own value in graph in x axis and y axis

Tags: android, charts

I have to make graph and I am able to do but I am not able to change value in x and y axis.

This is I have developed so far

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0AvS.png
```

using this for creating chart https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

here is the code

```
 <lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.ColumnChartView
                        android:id="@+id/chart"

                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp" />



private void generateDefaultData() {
        int numSubcolumns = 2;
        int numColumns = 6;
        // Column can have many subcolumns, here by default I use 1 subcolumn in each of 7 columns.
        List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
        List<SubcolumnValue> values;


        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; ++i) {

            values = new ArrayList<SubcolumnValue>();
            for (int j = 0; j < numSubcolumns; ++j) {
                if(j==1) {
                    values.add(new SubcolumnValue(2, -13388315));
                }
                else{
                    values.add(new SubcolumnValue(6, -5609780));

                }
                }

            Column column = new Column(values);
          // column.setHasLabels(hasLabels);
          //  column.setHasLabelsOnlyForSelected(hasLabelForSelected);
            columns.add(column);
        }

        data = new ColumnChartData(columns);

        if (hasAxes) {
            Axis axisX = new Axis();
            Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
            if (hasAxesNames) {
                axisX.setName("Days");
                axisY.setName("Y Axis");
            }
            data.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
            data.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
        } else {
            data.setAxisXBottom(null);
            data.setAxisYLeft(null);
        }

        Chart.setColumnChartData(data);
       // prepareDataAnimation();
        //Chart.startDataAnimation();

    }
```

What I want I want left axis to show only 1,3,5,7 and y axis to show day 1,day 2,day3 day4,day5,day6 .How Can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its late. But here's the solution.
you can use a list of AxisValue to set x-axis or y-axis value

```
List<AxisValue> axisValues = new ArrayList<>();
Axis axisY = new Axis();

axisValues.add(new AxisValue(0).setLabel("day 1"));
axisY.setValues(axisValues);
data.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.